# Get row count from unique ID's

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, rowcount

Let's suppose that I have this simple `n-n` table (between `people` and `product`):

```
//id    people_id    product_id
  1         1            1  
  2         1            3  
  3         1            5
  4         2            1
```

And this class (already mapped):

```
public class PeopleProduct
{
    public virtual int TableId { get; set; } //Mapped to id
    public virtual int PeopleId { get; set; } //Mapped to people_id
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; } //Mapped to product_id
}
```

As you can see, there's two `people`, the first one with 3 `products` and the second one with just 1.

**How can I get the count of unique `people_id` using CreateCriteria?**

I'm currently trying to using this one:

```
var crit = StatelessSession.CreateCriteria<PeopleProduct>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Count<PeopleProduct>(c => c.PeopleId))
        .Add(Projections.Group<PeopleProduct>(g => g.PeopleId)));

var count = Convert.ToInt64(crit.UniqueResult());
```

But it always returns a list with an array with [count, id]:

```
[3, 1] and [2, 1]
```

This is not the best result, since this table could return thousands of `people_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CountDistinct`.

```
var numberOfDistinctPeople = StatelessSession.CreateCriteria<PeopleProduct>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct<PeopleProduct>(c => c.PeopleId))
    .UniqueResult();
```

By the way, did you know that you can use `QueryOver`, which is the same with a better syntax? HQL / Linq is even more powerful and better to use for static queries like this one.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about it, but I was using `CreateCriteria` for other queries (customized by each table). Talking about `QueryOver`, is there any performance diff between both?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this worked!

```
var crit = StatelessSession.CreateCriteria<PeopleProduct>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Count(Projections.Distinct(
                    Projections.Property<PeopleProduct>(p => p.PeopleId)))));

var count = Convert.ToInt64(crit.UniqueResult());
```

EDIT: There's a better answer (and less verbose)...